# How to change ' ' to " " in json file

Tags: python, json, flask

How can I change the ' ' to " " ?
I need to write database.json using the data from sqlalchemy

> Data is the name of my database

```
all_data = Data.query.all()
data_schema = DataSchema(many=True)
output = data_schema.dump(all_data) 
OutputJson = jsonify({'products':output})

while True:
    with open('database.json',"w") as file:
        file.write(str({'products': output}))
    
    with open('database.json',"r") as files:
        FinalOutput = files.read()

        return FinalOutput
```

But my output is this:

```
{'products': [
    {'id': 0,
     'name': 0,
     'price': 0,
     'quantity': 1
    }
]}
```

and it should be like that:

```
{
  "products": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Aspirina",
      "price": 100,
      "quantity": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Where's the function for the `return`?

Comment: Use `json.dumps` or `json.dump` to produce JSON, not `str`.

Comment: Also, whatever `jsonify` is may already be doing the right thing. You aren't actually using `OutputJson` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this part:

```py
with open('database.json',"w") as file:
        file.write(str({'products': output}))
```

as

```py
import json
json_data = {}
with open('database.json',"r") as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)
json_data['products'] = output
with open('database.json',"w+") as file:
        json.dump(json_data)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to read from a file opened in write mode, and why are you opening  the file in read-write mode the second time?

Comment: @chepner edited, first read, second write

Comment: I fix it !!  with open('mercadopygo/database.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
  json.dump({'products': output}, file, indent=4)
 Thank everyone

Comment: @nikhouldan if this is the accepted answer, grateful if you can mark it as such!